# Can I use Entity Framework 6 with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Our development team (and build servers) successfully use a mixture of Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 for our application.

However, since upgrading from EF5 to EF6, we no longer seem to be able to build with VS2010.
Specifically, the build machines won't build at all. VS2010 on my desktop does seem to build, but I get the following errors:

```
Error   4   Error 10023: Could not find the conceptual model to validate. 
Error   5   Error 10024: Could not find the storage model to validate.
Error   6   Error 10025: Could not find the mapping model to validate.
```

Edit:

Our build machines do not have .Net 4.5, our Desktop machines (due to IT policy) do have .Net 4.5. On the machines without 4.5, we also get the following, which prevent assembly generation.

```
Could not find the Conceptual Schema node to embed as a resource for input file
```

Comment: rob, i believe there's a web.config setting to use EF5 when running .net v4.0. if i could rmbr the exact detail would add as an answer, but hopefully this will get you on your way

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use EF6 runtime with .NET Framework 4/Visual Studio 2010 however EF6 tooling does not support VS2010. EF tooling was updated to work with EF6 for VS2012 and VS2013. In other words on VS2010 and EF6 you can do CodeFirst but not ModelFirst/DatabaseFirst.

Comment: Can you use reverse-engineer code first with VS2010 and EF6?  Thanks!

Comment: @JosephDoggie - not with the built-in tooling - the EF6 capable tooling only supports VS2012 and VS2013. You may try EF Power Tools or install an express version of VS2013 (which is free) which contains EF6 capable tooling.

Comment: By runtime, do you mean to perhaps make a separate library (dll) with the EF6 Model in it and then reference it with your VS2010 project? If that's the case, then it works for me.