# Entity Framework missing ef designer from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I am running VS 2010 SP1.  I installed nuget package manager and from there installed Entity Framework 6.

However when I add an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" and go into the wizard I only see 2 options under the "Choose Model Contents"

Generate from database

Empty model

Why am I not seeing these other options?

EF Designer from Database

Empty EF Designer model

Empty Code First model

Code First from database

Comment: This is a total shot in the dark (I see those options in 2013), but is it possible that you need to install an additional NuGet package?

Comment: I checked and didn't see anything.

Comment: Is this the issue? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21031149/386703

Comment: It could possibly be an issue with EF6 not fully functional with VS2010.

Comment: Anyone know how to install a specific version of EF?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx ?